# Flask Post Request containing image file is only successful on second attempt

Tags: post, flask, fetch

I have created a web page which allows the user to upload an image. This image is then processed by a Python script hosted on a (local) Flask Server.

Everything works fine if the current URL is "index.html?file=[nameOfFileIAmTryingToUpload]".
But if the URL is just "index.html" or the file name belongs to another file than the one
I am currently trying to upload, the request will reach the Flask Server without any Files attached.

After the first attempt, the URL is changed to "index.html?file=[nameOfFileIAmTryingToUpload]". If I now try to resubmit the same file, it will work.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="return postData(this)">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function postData(data) {

    var photo = document.querySelector('#file').files[0]
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', photo);

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", { method: 'POST', body: data })
        .then(function(response) {
            response.text().then(function (text) {
                console.log(text);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {            
            console.log(error);    
        });
}
```

Python:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def returnResult():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']        

        if file:            
            # Do something
            return "File Uploaded Successfully"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution or work-around myself. 
It was enough to remove the form element in the HTML and instead use an Event Listener in the JS with the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {                        
        postData(this.files)
    }
});
```

});